# Python, Explain def function and scoring system?

Tags: python

Can someone explain this piece of code to allow me to understand def functions better, i need to know how the code below acts as a counter and adds up the score at the end of the test,:

```
for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
if quiz():
    score +=1
```

this code was for a test I created, if it can be explained thanks alot, also can someone maybe give an alternative version of this piece of code, the whole code is below :

```
import random
import math
import operator as op 

name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hi {}! Welcome to the Arithmetic quiz...".format(name)) 

score = 0
questions = 10

def quiz():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)

    ops = {'+': op.add,'-': op.sub,'*': op.mul} 

    keys = list(ops.keys()) 
    opt = random.choice(keys)  
    operation = ops[opt]  

    answer = operation(x, y)

    print ("What is {} {} {}?".format(x, opt, y)) #prints the question
    user_answer= int(input("Your answer: ")) #prompts users answer

    if user_answer != answer: #validate users answer to correct answer
        print ("Incorrect. The right answer is",answer"")
        return False
    else:
        print("Correct!")
        return True

for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
    if quiz():
        score +=1 #counter


print("{}: You got {}/{} questions correct.".format(name, score, questions,))#'question' if (score==1) else 'questions'
```

thanks <3

Comment: `def` defines a function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I knew that...=D, but i need to know how the code at the top of the page allows a counter to add up all the correct answers in the quiz

Comment: Please look at my new question please it is the other part of my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> i need to know how the code at the top of the page allows a counter to add up all the correct answers in the quiz

Formatting matters in Python, so take care:

```
for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
    if quiz():
        score +=1
```

`quiz()` gets called 10 times, and returns `True` if a question was answered correctly. In this case, the variable `score` will be [incremented](http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook006.html).

Comment: Oh My, its all clear now thanks a lot, really appreciate it thanks thanks thanks really clear explanation thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Consider chosing an accepted answer if it helped solving your problem.

Comment: Please look at my new question please it is the other part of my code

Comment: This seems like a new question, could you ask a new one and leave the old as-is (for future reference)? Also, please consider reading a tutorial like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) on Python dictionaries to get a basic understanding of `dictionaries` and `keys`.

Answer (score -1):

The `quiz` function asks a single question, takes the user's input, checks it and prints a message accordingly. It is defined in the block of code following `def quiz():` and it is called (run) with `quiz()`. It also returns the value `True` if the answer was correct or `False` if it was incorrect.

So, every time it is called, its return value is checked and if it's `True` (`if quiz():` is equivalent to `if quiz() == True:`), the counter `score` is incremented.

In fact, you can add `True` (which actually equals 1) and `False` (==0) to an integer, so your code (note the indenting):

```
for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
    if quiz():
        score +=1
```

could be written:

```
for i in range(questions): #ask 10 questions
    score += quiz()
```

Comment: oH wow, thanks or the alternative thanks gr8 explanation...<3